# Geting Data from a Tree Structure

Tags: c++, data-structures, tree

I have a tree structure that i am creating the following way. The tree is created correctly as far as i know. But when i want to get the data from a node, i get some weird acsii symbols.

How I set the data.Lets say its empty. Doesn't matter at the moment. I have a value in my program. The function feeds itself until i get to the end of the data.

```
struct Node {
    char Data;
    Node* Left;
    Node* Right;
};

Node maketree(0,s,split)
{
    Node node;
    node.Data=' ';

    Node n1=subsplit(0,s,splitingat);
    Node n2= subsplit(1,splitingat+1,e);
    node.Left=&n1;
    node.Right=&n2;

    return node; 
 }
```

This is how i get data from the tree.

```
char decode(Node node,string text)
{
    int currentindex=0;
    Node sub=node;
    {
    }
    if(text[currentindex]=='0')
    {
        sub=*sub.Left;
        cout<<" x "<<sub.Data<<endl;
    }
    else if(text[currentindex]=='1')
    {
        sub=*sub.Right;
        cout<<" x "<<sub.Data<<endl;
    }

   // cout<<sub.Data<<endl;
}
```

I think that the mistake is that I am printing out the pointer and not the node. But I don't know where I went wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The source of your problem appears to be here:

```
Node node;
node.Data=' ';

Node n1=subsplit(0,s,splitingat);
Node n2= subsplit(1,splitingat+1,e);
node.Left=&n1; // danger Will Robinson!
node.Right=&n2;

return node;
```

You're taking the addresses of local, temporary, automatic variables and storing them in pointers that you return through `node`. As soon as that `return` executes, `n1` and `n2` are destroyed and `node.Left` and `node.Right` are left pointing to garbage. You *may* be able to fix this like so:

```
Node* n1=new Node(subsplit(0,s,splitingat)); 
Node* n2=new Node(subsplit(1,splitingat+1,e));
// side note: probably better to have subsplit() return dynamically-allocated Node*s to avoid the copy
node.Left=n1;
node.Right=n2;
```

but you may still have issues crop up if similar things are being done elsewhere.

Kind of along the same lines, in your second block of code, you are making a *copy* of each node you examine and storing it into `sub`. It would probably make more sense to have `sub` be a `Node*`.

And finally, to avoid memory management issues (almost) altogether, use `shared_ptr<Node>` instead of `Node*` in all of the above. :)

Comment: Thanks that works amazing. Can i check node.Left==nill ? will that work

Comment: Not quite sure I understand, but the syntax to check for null would be `Node.Left==nullptr`. Also, if you're allocating your `Node`s with `new` now and weren't before, remember you'll have to `delete` them when you're done. Unless you switch to `shared_ptr`. :)

Comment: thank you u helped me a lott. Its a more or less statick decoding program for collage so memmory alocation, is my second worry. I need to get it working first.